# How to access Wordpress admin panel after integration with Codeigniter?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter-2

In the company where I work we used to have Wordpress on its own subdomain, like blog.ourwebsite.com. We decided that it would've been better to have it in the main domain, like: ourwebsite.com/blog. Also, we want it perfectly integrate with our current design, so the blog should load inside the website showing just the posts, while the header and the footer will be the one of our website. Our website is built with Codeigniter.
I've read different articles and questions about how to integrate the two platforms and in the end we opted for putting Wordpress inside the root directory of the Codeigniter installation, so that it looks like this:

```
ourwebsite/
    application/
    system/
    wordpress_blog/
```

In the Codeigniter `index.php` I am loading Wordpress with this instruction:

```
require_once './wpblog/wp-blog-header.php';
```

I put it on top, so before loading the codeigniter core. At this point the only problem was the `site_url` function conflict which I solved by renaming it in Codeigniter. So, everything seems to work fine except that I have no idea how to access the Wordpress administration panel.

I then created a `blog` controller and I can now call Wordpress functions inside the Codeigniter view. So at this point the Wordpress content is displayed correctly. The problem is that I have no idea how to access the Wordpress admin panel. If I try to access `localhost/ourwebsite/en/blog/wp-admin` I, of course, get an error, because it's trying to access a `wp-admin` function inside the controller, which doesn't exist. So I was thinking to access directly the directory with something like `localhost/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/wp-admin` (wordpress_blog is the name of the directory on disk, which is different from the controller name), but I get a 404 error. I also added this directory to the Codeigniter `.htaccess` file that now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ourwebsite/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|wordpress_blog|cache|captcha|fonts|forum|media|img|min|css|js|scripts|images|uploads|docs|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap|public|tools|assets|xd_receiver.htm)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any idea?

EDIT:
I tried accessing directly the `wp-login.php` file, at `http://localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/wp-login.php`. This actually works. The thing is that when I try to login it redirects me to a wrong url, which is: `http://localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/wp-admin/localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F~carlo%2Fourwebsite%2Fwpblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`.
The thing is that it logged me in anyway, so if I try to access the admin panel again, now, it kind of works. I can see it but it's like it has no css or javascript files loaded.

Comment: IS that 404 error Coming from Ci or Wordress

Comment: It doesn't have the layout of a Codeigniter error page. In the apache error log it says this: `script '/var/www/wp-login.php' not found or unable to stat`, which is strange because my web root is in `/home/carlo/public_html/`

Comment: can you access your wordpress directry localhost/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/

Comment: Yes, I can. When I add the `wp-admin` fragment at the end it gets redirected to: `http://localhost/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F~carlo%2Fourwebsite%2Fwpblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok then try to change the wordpress siteurl in option table. it should be like localhost/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/.. 
and check your 
localhost/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/wp-admin

**edited 2/11/2014**

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/');
```

you are missing "http://"

Comment: ok, this was something I've tried, but forgot to mention in the question. I've actually set the values for `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in the `wp-config.php` file. Setting them with `localhost/~carlo/photocircle/wpblog/` as a value, when I try to access the admin panel it redirects me to `http://localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wpblog/wp-admin/localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wpblog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F~carlo%2Fourwebsite%2Fwpblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Comment: As you said {{{{ When I add the wp-admin fragment at the end it gets redirected to: http://localhost/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F~carlo%2Four‌​website%2Fwpblog%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 }} http://localhost/wp-login.php?.. happens to be pulled from the site url with wp-login.php.. so i assumed that your site url is not defined properly so juss suggested you to put http://localhost/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/ as your site url. wp-redirect is working so the admin section is. might be issue with htaccess

Comment: have you tried with http://localhost/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/ as your WP_SITEURL

Comment: I've just tried, but it's the same. Anyway, the `~carlo/` segment is correct, because it's how I set up my local environment and I use it to access the webroot. I posted the Codeigniter .htaccess in the answer, but in the Wordpress directory I don't have any .htaccess

Comment: Can you show me your config file where you have added your siteurl.

Comment: on top of the `wp-config.php` file I inserted these two lines: `define('WP_HOME','localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/');
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/~carlo/ourwebsite/wordpress_blog/');`

Comment: ok, I edited it so many times I really didn't notice. Thank you!